# How to solve ASCII=92 error and will it be possible to run laravel 4 project on php 5.2 server ?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am getting error like this ,

`Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/dolovers/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46`

and

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/dolovers/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46`

My current version of web server php is 5.2 is that the reason for that ?

my second question is, Is is possible to run Laravel 4 projects on php 5.2 servers ? If not then what will be the good server to buy for laravel 4. And during its selection what should I take care of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` character is the `namespace separator`, and since Laravel 4 uses namespaces and PHP 5.2 does **not** support them, it triggers a syntax error and you cannot use Laravel 4 on that version of PHP.

By the way, support for PHP 5.2 has been long since dropped, you should consider upgrading to the latest version of the 5.5.x branch.

Comment: thank you for you reply , Sir wld you pls inform me that is it the concern of hosting company or just me(to update the version) to have this support (a upper version of php)?

Comment: Well, if you are on paid hosting, I guess you could ask them to upgrade at least to version 5.3 if at all possible... If the server is yours, then it is up to you to update. If my answer helped you, fell free to upvote it and/or accept it :)